# Current values verification check without ammeter

Tags: circuit-analysis, verification

Given the following circuit with my current directions (the ones I highlighted with red):

[image]

So \$ I = - 2  A, I' = -1.5 A, I_x = \frac{1}{2} A , I_y = -1.5A , V_x = -1.5 A \$

Is this valid?

Comment: Please post a solution to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$I\$ has to be -2 amps because the 1 Ω resistor above the 2 volt source has an unambiguous 2 volts across it (the difference between 4 volts and 2 volts).

And, \$I\$ must be 4 times \$-I_x\$ due to this image: -

[image]

In other words, the current flowing downwards through the 2 volt source has to be \$4\cdot I_x\$ by simple inspection. And because \$I\$ =  -2 amps, \$I_x\$ = 0.5 amps.

It then follows that \$I^{'}\$ = -1.5 amps and, \$I_y\$ is +1.5 amps and not -1.5 amps.

---

**Errata**

As Mohamed points out and argues, \$I_y\$ is actually -1.5 amps. My error. My brain-fart.

Comment: no i dont agree with \$I_y = +1.5 A \$

Comment: LKC at the right most node is \$ 3 A = 3I_x - I_y \$

Comment: Yes, you are quite correct.

Comment: so \$ I_y = -1.5 A \$

Comment: Yes it does. I'll update my answer.